How do I use EditThisCookie data with requests?
I want to use cookie from EditThisCookie in order to get available items from account, so I saved them in a 'cookie.json' file, but when I'm trying to use them and send a get request, its just not logging in
Sample of 'cookies.json':
[
{
    "domain": ".github.com",
    "expirationDate": 12401290312391203012,
    "hostOnly": false,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_octo",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "lax",
    "secure": true,
    "session": false,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "MIGHT_BE_SMTH_PERSONAL :(",
    "id": 1
}
]

btw, expirationDate and value values are hidden, cuz I don't know what people can do with it
Code:
import requests
import json
url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/steamid/730/2?&count=5000'

with open('cookies.json', 'r') as f:
    json_data = f.read()
    parsed_data = json.loads(json_data)
    if isinstance(parsed_data, list) and all(isinstance(item, dict) for item in parsed_data):  
        cookies = parsed_data
    else:
        cookies = []

r = requests.Session()

for cookie in cookies:
    r.cookies.update(cookie)

headers = {
    'User-Agent' : 'my_user_agent'
}


r.get(url, headers=headers)


So, I solved it, the final code for those who needs it :
import requests
import json


url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/steamid/730/2?&count=5000'

with open('cookies.json', 'r') as f:
    json_data = f.read()
    parsed_data = json.loads(json_data)
    if isinstance(parsed_data, list) and all(isinstance(item, dict) for item in parsed_data):  
        cookies = parsed_data
    else:
        cookies = []

session = requests.Session()

for cookie in cookies:
    session.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])

headers = {
    'User-Agent' : 'my_user_agent'
}



response = session.get(url)

print(response.text)

#Getting the whole inventory page content

and you don't need to change any data in your 'cookies.json' (I wrote that you need above)

The error as you can read on the end of the output is a TypeError as the expiration date should be a string and not a float like it probably is right now. Changing the expiration date to a str should fix the issue.

I tried changing data and it only helped to fix this particular error, but it's not helping to log into steam account using cookie
